# How to keep the changed value?

Tags: r, database

I met a problem when I am dealing with value change by using `lead()`.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13),
                 drug_type = c("A","A","B","C","B","B","B","B","A","A","B","B"),
                 drug_brand = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,3),
                 date = c("2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-13",
                          "2019-04-05","2019-05-02","2019-06-03","2019-08-04",
                          "2021-02-02","2021-02-27","2021-03-22","2021-04-11"))
```

As for the data frame shown above, I aim to identify the change in drug type for each patient, if there is no change in the drug type for a patient, then they will be ignored. To achieve it I used

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(lead(drug_type)=="B")
```

However, it only returned the corresponding rows whose next value is "B", while **I want to also keep the  rows containing changed values. For example, in terms of patient no.11, the result only returned me the record on the "2020-02-01", but I hope to find a way to keep the record on the "2020-03-01" as well, that is, the changed value**.

I tried some ways, including creating extra columns named "next" showing the next values of each value in the drug type, but they are either wrong or excessively redundant. Therefore, I want to know if there is any better way to achieve my goal.

Comment: What do you want to do with id=12?  No change in drug for that patient. In my answer that px is dropped completely, because there is no change. Perhaps let us know if that was your intent or not?

Comment: @langtang Thanks for your comment. As #12 doesn't change drug type, I will ignore him.  Your advice is really helpful, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if drug type differs from `lead()` or if drug type differs from `lag()`

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(
    (drug_type!=lag(drug_type)) |
      drug_type!=lead(drug_type)
  )
```

Output:

```
     id drug_type drug_brand date      
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     
1    11 A                  1 2020-02-01
2    11 B                  2 2020-03-01
3    11 C                  2 2020-03-13
4    13 A                  1 2021-02-27
5    13 B                  2 2021-03-22
```

If you only want rows that change to "B" plus the row that has that new "B" value, you could do something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  filter((drug_type!="B" & lead(drug_type)=="B") | drug_type=="B" & lag(drug_type)!="B")
```

Output:

```
     id drug_type drug_brand date      
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     
1    11 A                  1 2020-02-01
2    11 B                  2 2020-03-01
3    13 A                  1 2021-02-27
4    13 B                  2 2021-03-22
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is really a great way because I don't need to see the next value on 2020-03-13. No matter what it is, the record on 2020-03-01 will be kept.